# How to actually track S3 upload progress (JavaScript SDK)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to be able to track an S3 file upload's progress (bytes uploaded out of bytes total).

Before anyone flags this as a dupe—it's not. Every other answer I've seen on StackOverflow is actually incorrect. If you do something like this:

```
s3
  .putObject(
    {
      Bucket: 'xyz',
      Key: 'wow.png',
      Body: data,
    },
    (err, data) => {
      console.log('done', err, data);
    }
  )
  .on('httpUploadProgress', progress => {
    console.log('Progress:', progress);
  });
```

You get a single progress update, showing the total size:

```
Progress { loaded: 1082019, total: 1082019 }
```

This is not useful. What I'm looking for is a more fine-grained report of upload progress like you would normally see during an upload (no matter the file size.. 1MB or 100MB):

0% out of 100%
3% out of 100%
7% out of 100%
9% out of 100%
(etc)

Comment: Please define "fine-grained report of upload progress". What information exactly do you want?

Comment: Edited. I'm looking for regular progress updates as the upload progresses.

Comment: Did you tried a ManagedUpload?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work for me because your part size has to be at least 5MB. And then it would only report on each 5MB part being done. That's not useful to a user.

Comment: 5 MB is the default part size but you can adjust that using [minPartSize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#minPartSize-property) as long as you do not exceed the [maxTotalParts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#maxTotalParts-property) (default is 10000. Configurable also).

Comment: I tried that too, setting `minPartSize` to 250Kb. It ignored that and told me the minimum part size was 5MB.

Comment: I’m going to see if I can hook into the raw XMLHttpRequest somehow.

Comment: BTW, adjusting part size isn't ideal either. If I dialed down the part size to 50KB to better track uploads, it would result in a ton of parts uploading at once which is probably not a good idea.

Does anyone know how to access the raw XHR in S3?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1323

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is the answer (as lame as it is). Just sharing this as it could be a potential gotcha for other people.

This *will not* work in a Node.js environment! I've been testing this in that manner, and it just calls the `httpUploadProgress` callback once. Once I moved my code to an actual front-end client, it works as expected and prints the progress as the file uploads.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1945#issuecomment-367936328 - "In browsers, the SDK adds an event listener to the underlying XmlHttpRequest’s progress event. In Node, progress is detected by the body stream being read"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s3
.putObject({
        Bucket: 'xyz',
        Key: 'wow.png',
        Body: data,
    },
    (err, data) => {
        console.log('done', err, data);
    }
)
.on('httpUploadProgress', ({ loaded, total }) => {
    console.log(ContentType, 'Progress:', loaded, '/', total, `${Math.round(100 * loaded / total)}%`);
})
```